# How to waits for user inputs in docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run the container I have used following command:

```
docker run -it -v /home/config --name appli <dockerid>/<docker-image>
```

It waits until user inputs the login details.

But when I run the command without `-it` the container skip the user input line and executes other lines. This is the same issue when I run the docker-compose file. I want to execute docker-compose file as same as the docker run -it command.

[screen shot for te command docker run with -it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LslLx.png)

[screen shot of the output when run the docker-compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c88EQ.png)

Comment: More details needed on how it works on your normal docker run, provide your Dockerfile , compose file.

Comment: Please modify your question keeping this in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example mind

Comment: Generally you don't: `docker-compose up` doesn't expect to run interactive processes.  (If you had _two_ containers that expected input like this, and you typed a response, which container would it go to?)  It's better to use a mechanism like environment variables to configure your applications non-interactively.